# Таблица SQL создание диалогов (Мессенджер)

Tags: sql

я делаю свой мессенджер. Собственно можно сделать всё в одну таблицу

```
id
user_from
user_to
text
is_read
timestamp
```

Есть нюанс, мне нужны еще настройки диалогов. Закреплен ли диалог, убран ли в архив. Поэтому я сделал еще одну таблицу, но уже вижу в ней тупик и не могу понять как правильно построить запрос вывода всех диалогов только по одному типу (Например мы открыли архивные сообщения).

```
id
uid1
uid2
u1_type - Убрал ли первый юзер в архив диалог
u2_type - Убрал ли второй юзер в архив диалог
last_update - Дата последнего сообщения, для ORDER BY last_update DESC
```

Так вот, если я пишу запрос `WHERE uid1 = 1 OR uid2 = 1`, то как мне сделать фильтр по настройки u1 или u2 мне нужен? Потому что значение настройки для юзера может быть и там и там. Или создавать еще одну таблицу dialog_settings? Тогда как по ней фильтровать? Через `left join`?

Comment: не понятно что вы ищите запросом uid1=1 or uid2=2 вы же получите много записей где либо один пользователь либо другой. (при этом не найдете uid2=1 например). сформулируйте точно в впоросе что именно вы хотите найти и какие данные у вас при этом есть для поиска

Comment: @Mike я ищу все диалоги пользователя с ID = 1. При этом у пользователя есть настройки, например часть диалогов в архиве. То есть type стоит 1. А мы ищем по поиску type=0. Но этот type может лежать и в u1 и u2. Поэтому таблица уже криво построена, я не совсем догоняю как сделать ее правильно.

Comment: Но тогда у вас запрос бы выглядел как uid1=1 or uid2=1 а не разные id там были, как вы написали в вопросе. А нужную настройку всегда можно вытащить как `select case when uid1=1 then u1_type else u2_type end ...`. Но да, вообще все выглядит криво. Особенно если завтра вы решите сделать групповые чаты

Comment: @Mike ой, извините, опечатался в запросе.

Comment: Если замахиваться на большее, то должна быть таблица самих чатов. в которой в общем то только id самого чата и может какие общие характеристики вроде топика, логотипа, дата последнего сообщения (под вопросом, 5ю форму оно нарушает но для быстродействия может и пригодиться). вторая таблица пользователи в чатах где id чата, id пользователя, его настройки. И для начала делаете что бы в этой таблице для каждого чата было всегда ровно 2 записи (для одного и второго пользователя). Но если завтра решите сделать групповые - просто позволите добавлять туда еще записи.